# Changing CSS font size with browser window

Tags: javascript, css, browser, fonts

Is this possible with css or javascript? So If I want 20pt font or 1em font or similar at a certain browser size but the font to shrink and expand if the browser window shrinks or expands? Thanks

Comment: CSS3 Values and Units covers relative sizing based on the viewport but it's currently only supported by IE9.    http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Answer (score 2):

You can use the onResize event to do this. jQuery can be utilized to do this, for example: http://api.jquery.com/resize/ . You only need to apply proper CSS changes on specific elements.

Answer (score 2):

there is no proper css solution that I know of. You can define font-size in % but it will take a % of the pixels of the parent elements font.

You could use mediaqueries, but they will become bigger in steps not fluent.

```
.p {
   font-size: 20px; 
}    
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .p {
   font-size: 12px; 
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .p {
   font-size: 14px; 
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .p {
   font-size: 16px; 
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .p {
   font-size: 18px; 
  }
}
```

Comment: He is trying to do this when browser is resized, CSS has nothing to do here because it can't read / operate on browser viewport size.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the units vw (viewport) when defining the font size in the css file and it will scale up or down with the size of the window.
Example:

```
body {
    font-size: 10vw;
}
```

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not depend on (non-widely supported parts of) CSS3 or Javascript to work. It uses media queries to change the font-size but thanks to employing [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) it is expressed concisely and it very easy to use:

http://github.com/wadim/responsive-font-size

Supplied with four parameters this mixin will intelligently figure out the right media-query definitions for you.